# Get the real import symbol address on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c, nginx, visual-c++, dll, disassembly

Can someone explain why I cannot get the corresponding address with `req->request_body->post_handler` from `ngx_http_upstream_init` and how to get it correctly?

Code Snippet:

```cpp
// Note: for debug test only
// https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14422/how-do-i-know-the-bytes-corresponding-to-an-instruction-in-hex-view-in-ida
logdf("%p, %p", ngx_http_upstream_init, req->request_body->post_handler);
ngx_http_upstream_init(req);
req->request_body->post_handler(req);
assert(ngx_http_upstream_init == req->request_body->post_handler);
// Skip post_handler because we don't want to create the upstream to the proxied server right now.
return NGX_HTTP_EM_HAS_SUBREQUEST(req) && 0 == req->request_body->rest ? NGX_AGAIN : NGX_OK;
```

The log:

```
ngx_http_request_body_filter_by_em|2681|00007FFACC961617, 00007FF727A8BA37
```

And, in the Disassembly window,

```
                ;ngx_http_upstream_init(req);
00007FFACC9E66D1 48 8B 8D C0 01 00 00 mov         rcx,qword ptr [req]  
00007FFACC9E66D8 E8 3A AF F7 FF       call        ngx_http_upstream_init (07FFACC961617h)  
                ;req->request_body->post_handler(req);
00007FFACC9E66DD 48 8B 85 C0 01 00 00 mov         rax,qword ptr [req]  
00007FFACC9E66E4 48 8B 80 90 03 00 00 mov         rax,qword ptr [rax+390h]  
00007FFACC9E66EB 48 8B 8D C0 01 00 00 mov         rcx,qword ptr [req]  
00007FFACC9E66F2 FF 50 40             call        qword ptr [rax+40h]
```

Howerver, in the Immediate Window (corresponding to tooltip mouse when hovering my mouse cursor over them in VS2017):

```
ngx_http_upstream_init
0x00007ffacc9f6041 {ngx_http_em_module.dll!ngx_http_upstream_init}
req->request_body->post_handler
0x00007ff727a8ba37 {NGINX.exe!ngx_http_upstream_init}
```

I found its output is different from the previous two cases.

Some pictures,

[image: Disassembly of c++ code]

[image: Disassembly from module.dll!ngx_http_upstream_init to NGINX.exe!ngx_http_upstream_init]

[image: Disassembly from req->request_body->post_handler]

[image: IDA View]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed that I didn't add `extern __declspec(dllimport)` to import the function symbol , so the compiler didn't add a stub entry in the import table, i.e. the `.idata` segment/section,  and a jump code in the `.text` segment/section, but just generated multiple jump codes.

After adding it like this,

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288293/windows-c-extern-declspecdllimport
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772839/def-file-vs-declspecdllexport-macro
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/definitions-and-declarations-cpp?view=msvc-160
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/exports?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-160
// Note, in order to minimize modification, we use a .DEF file (one of four ways) to export a definition.
// grep --color -RP 'NGX_API (?!ngx_module)' /cygdrive/c/nginx --include=\*.{c,h}
// grep --color -R 'extern ' /cygdrive/c/nginx --include=\*.{c,h} -l | xargs sed -i 's/extern /NGX_API /g'
// grep --color -r 'NGX_API ngx_module_t' /cygdrive/c/nginx --include=\*.{c,h} -l | xargs sed -i 's/NGX_API ngx_module_t/extern ngx_module_t/g'
// NGX_API2: mainly used to distinguish between original extern symbols and those symbols we expect to export/import
#ifdef NGX_IMPORTS
#define NGX_API extern __declspec(dllimport)
#define NGX_API2 NGX_API
#else
#define NGX_API extern
#define NGX_API2
#endif

// nginx\src\http\ngx_http_upstream.h
NGX_API2 void ngx_http_upstream_init(ngx_http_request_t *r);
```

I got  the desired result.

```
ngx_http_request_body_filter_by_em|2681|00007FF7E89BBA37, 00007FF7E89BBA37
```

[image: IDA view in .idata and .text]

[image: Disassembly in Visual Studio 2017]

In the Immediate Window,

```
r9
140702736169527

ngx_http_upstream_init
0x00007ffacaf06840 {ngx_http_enforcer_module.dll!ngx_http_upstream_init}

req->request_body->post_handler
NGINX.exe!0x00007ff7e89bba37 (load symbols for additional information)

0x00007ff7e89bba37
140702736169527
```